# How to specify only few type of a polymorphic method

Tags: scala

Given the following code

```
def doAction[A:Reads, B:Writes](bizMethod: A => B) = …
def f = doAction(g)
```

In some cases, the compiler can't infer the type. For example, `g` input parameters is not convertible to `Reads`, but we will call the method with an instance of a subclass that is Readable. So I want to fix the first type and let the compiler determines the second one, as `def f =
 doAction[XXX, _](g)`

[update] For a better comprehension of the issue, I've add code to illustrate the question :

```
trait Sth[A]
implicit val StringSth = new Sth[String]{}
def doAction[A:Sth,B:Sth](f: A => B) = f

def g(i: String) = "Str" + i
val gg = doAction(g)

def h(a: Any) = a.toString
def hh = doAction(h) // doesn't compile, it's normal
def hh[String] = doAction[String, _](h) //doesn't compile
```

I want to call `hh` with a `String`

Comment: I can't even begin to image how many times I've wanted this or how many hours I've spent on workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question, but it sounds as though you're after type lambdas.

You'll find lots of matches if you search Google for the term, but [this](https://github.com/earldouglas/scala-scratchpad/tree/master/type-lambdas) is probably the cleanest explanation.

**UPDATE**

In this case, the easiest way is just to use *type ascription* and inform the compiler that you'll be using `h` as though it were an instance of `String => String` (which is valid, because contravariance means that `String=>String` is a superclass of `Any=>String`).

Then you can let the rest of the implicit machinery work without further tweaks:

```
val h = (a: Any) => a.toString
val hh = doAction(h: String => String)
```

As an added benefit, the intent of your code is far clearer if you do it this way.

Comment: I've updated the answer to precise my use case. lambda seems overkill in my case, right ?

Comment: is there a way to omit the return type `val hh = doAction(h: String => _)` ? (to let the compiler infer it)